# I want to add background color to some grid boxes. How should I do that?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, for-loop

I want to get an emoji face from providing background colors. I mean if user select smiley 1 from drop down it need to show a happy emoji face. For that I want to pass all array data (smile 1) into that x variable to change the background color of those grid boxes. But from the above code I get an error. Please help me.

Comment: please use the SO code snippet and write your code into the correct sections so it can be parsed. You also missing the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```js
console.clear()
{
// Make own object with many smilies
  const smilies = {};
  smilies.smile1 = [
      [0, 4],[0, 5],[0, 6],[0, 7],
      [1, 2],[1, 3],[1, 8],[1, 9],
      [2, 1],[2, 10],
      [3, 1],[3, 10],
      [4, 0],[4, 4],[4, 7],[4, 11],
      [5, 0],[5, 4],[5, 7],[5, 11],
      [6, 0],[6, 11],
      [7, 0],[7, 3],[7, 8],[7, 11],
      [8, 1],[8, 4],[8, 5],[8, 6],[8, 7],[8, 10],    
      [9, 1],[9, 10],
      [10, 2],[10, 3],[10, 8],[10, 9],    
      [11, 4],[11, 5],[11, 6],[11, 7]
  ];

  smilies.smile2 = [
      [0, 4],[0, 5],[0, 6],[0, 7],
      [1, 2],[1, 3],[1, 8],[1, 9],
      [2, 1],[2, 10],
      [3, 1],[3, 10],
      [4, 0],[4, 3],[4, 4],[4, 6],[4, 7],[4, 11],
      [5, 0],[5, 4],[5, 7],[5, 11],
      [6, 0],[6, 11],
      [7, 0],[7, 8],[7, 11],
      [8, 1],[8, 3],[8, 4],[8, 5],[8, 6],[8, 7],[8, 10],    
      [9, 1],[9, 10],
      [10, 2],[10, 3],[10, 8],[10, 9],    
      [11, 4],[11, 5],[11, 6],[11, 7]
  ];
  
  var menu = document.getElementById("container");

  for (var i = 0; i < 144; i++) {
    var cell = document.createElement("div");

    menu.appendChild(cell);
  }

  var smi1 = document.getElementById("select");

  smi1.addEventListener("change", myFunction);

  function myFunction(e) {
    var x = document.getElementById("container").querySelectorAll("div");
    
    
    // get the smily from the selected value
    var smilie = smilies[e.target.value];
    // clean the grid
    for (var i = 0; i < 144; i++) {
      x[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < smilie.length; i++) {
      // HTML elements are in sequence, not in a grid. To calculate the grid item wo choose you have to 
      // multiplicate the row number by 12, because there are 12 items per row and add the column number
      x[smilie[i][0] * 12 + smilie[i][1]].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}

section#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 30px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 30px);
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Select the pixelated image you want to see
    <form>
      <select name="image" id="select">
        <option value='' readonly>Select one option</option>
        <option value='smile1'>Smiley 1</option>
        <option value='smile2'>Smiley 2</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </h1>
</section>
<section id="container">

</section>
```

Comment: nice that you fixed it, but could you also explain for others how you did it? An anwser without explanation is quite useless for others to reproduce. But you already should know that...